# Is usage of eval is necessary here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a class that will remove records that were not updated from a certain time. For example, I need to remove all records that were not updated in the last 8 months. I have a worker class that looks like this:

```
class ConnectionsCleanerWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options queue: :connections_cleaner, retry: false

  def perform
    months = Figaro.env.connection_updated_months_ago
    Connection.where('updated_at < ?', eval("#{months}.months.ago")).destroy_all
  end
end
```

It works properly, but I'm wondering if there is any way to write this code without using `eval`.

Comment: `Connection.where('updated_at < ?', months.months.ago).destroy_all` - this should work fine. But what does `months.months.ago` returns ?

Comment: Why are you using eval in the first place?

Comment: @max, I assume for interpolation `"#{months}.months.ago`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need it. You can simply do: `3.moths.ago` on integer. This means that you can simply do `months.months.ago`.

```
period = Figaro.env.connection_updated_months_ago
Connection.where('updated_at < ?', period.months.ago)).destroy_all
```

Answer (score 1):

No. If `months` is `Fixnum`, it will work without `eval`. In other cases (`month` is a string), it is better to do something like:

```
def perform
  months_count = Figaro.env.connection_updated_months_ago.to_i
  Connection.where('updated_at < ?', months_count.months.ago)).destroy_all
end
```